# CVSNT: from a tag to a list of file names and revisions

Tags: windows, cvs, cvsnt

I have a project with sources under the control of CVSNT.

I need a list of source file names and revisions belonging to a certain tag.
For example:

```
the tag MYTAG is:
myproject/main.cpp 1.5.2.3
myproject/myclass.h 1.5.2.1
```

I know that with `cvs log -rMYTAG > log.txt` I get in `log.txt` all the information I need and then I can filter it to build my list, but, is there any utility which already do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Python script that does this:

```
import sys, os, os.path
import re, string

def runCvs(args):
  f_in, f_out, f_err = os.popen3('cvs '+string.join(args))
  out = f_out.read()
  err = f_err.read()
  f_out.close()
  f_err.close()
  code = f_in.close()
  if not code: code = 0
  return code, out, err

class RevDumper:
  def parseFile(self, rex, filelog):
    m = rex.search(filelog)
    if m:
      print '%s\t%s' % (m.group(1), m.group(2))

  def filterOutput(self, logoutput, repoprefix):
    rex = re.compile('^={77}$', re.MULTILINE)
    files = rex.split(logoutput)
    rex = re.compile('RCS file: %s(.*),v[^=]+selected revisions: [^0][^=]+revision ([0-9\.]+)' % repoprefix, re.MULTILINE)
    for file in files:
      self.parseFile(rex, file)

  def getInfo(self, tag, module, repoprefix):
    args = ['-Q', '-z9', 'rlog', '-S', '-N', '-r'+tag, module] # remove the -S if you're using an older version of CVS
    code, out, err = runCvs(args)
    if code == 0:
      self.filterOutput(out, repoprefix)
    else:
      sys.stderr.write('CVS returned %d\n%s\n' % (code, err))

if len(sys.argv) > 2:
  tag = sys.argv[1]
  module = sys.argv[2]
  if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    repoprefix = sys.argv[3]
  else:
    repoprefix = ''
  RevDumper().getInfo(tag, module, repoprefix)
else:
  sys.stderr.write('Syntax: %s TAG MODULE [REPOPREFIX]' % os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))
```

Note that you either have to have a `CVSROOT` environment variable set or run this from inside a working copy checked out from the repository you want to query.

Also, the file names displayed are based on the "RCS File" property of the `rlog` output, i.e. they still contain the repository prefix. If you want to filter that out you can specify a third argument, e.g. when your `CVSROOT` is something like `sspi:server:/cvsrepo` then you would call this like:

```
ListCvsTagRevisions.py MyTag MyModule /cvsrepo/
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Note:** If you need a script that lists the revisions currently in your working copy, see the edit history of this answer.

Comment: @uvts_cvs: No, this should work with anything from at least 2.5 upwards. I'm still on Python 2.6.5 myself, so I'm not actually sure it will work with 3. Note that the `-S`-option on the `cvs rlog` command requires a fairly recent version of CVS(NT). You can however safely remove it from the code: The query to the server will only need a little more bandwidth in that case.